# C#, WinForms and Extension Methods

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, extension-methods

**The Question**

Aside from all the obvious answers, what would cause extension methods to generate compiler errors like this one:

*'DataType' does not contain a definition for 'YourExtensionMethodName'*

I've got a real stumper here, and it's spelled out for you in detail below. I've exhausted all the possible causes I can think of.

**Scenario**

- I have a couple of extension methods defined in various static classes in a DLL that is consumed by a WinForms application.
- The extension method signatures do not conflict with the signatures of methods on the class I'm extending (`String`, in this case).
- Both the DLL and the WinForms application are written in C#.
- Both the DLL and the WinForms application are configured to target .NET 3.5.
- The consuming classes include a reference to the namespace that defines the extension method. Its spelling has been verified.
- If I reference the extension class directly, the extension methods appear. For example, if I type `StringExtensions.`, Intellisense appears as normal, with all of my extension methods listed.
- **EDIT**: The errors are occurring in the WinForms application, but only for *some* of the extension methods, not all of them.

**The Code (Or an Excerpt Thereof)**

(Yep, this is the offending code)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Roswell.Framework
{
    public static class StringBuilderExtensions
    {
        public static string ToSentenceCase(this string value)
        {
            return value.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper() + value.Substring(1).ToLower();
        }

        public static string ToTitleCase(this string value)
        {
            string[] parts = value.Split(new string[] {" "}, StringSplitOptions.None);
            System.Text.StringBuilder builder = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
            foreach (string part in parts)
            {

                builder.Append(part.ToSentenceCase());
                builder.Append(" ");
            }
            return builder.ToString();
        }

    }
}
```

And this is the code that consumes it:

```
using Roswell.Framework;

namespace Roswell.Windows.Command
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Views the SQL for an object in the database window.
    /// </summary>
    internal class ViewObjectDdlCommand
        : MainWindowCommand
    {

        public override void Execute()
        {
           // ...

           OpenCodeWindow(
               string.Format("{0} - {1} - {2}", 
                             dsn.Name, 
                             objectName, 
                             info.ToTitleCase()),
                schemaItemType,
                objectName);
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your code snippet, I can see you're calling `ToTitleCase` on something called `info`. But I can't see the type of that variable, which is the thing that will determine what is happening here.

Obviously it needs to be a string (if string was not a sealed class it could be something derived from string, but that's impossible for a sealed class).

So the only thing that makes sense (aside from a very unlikely compiler error) is that `info` is not a string.

Comment: You're right. This was a clear-cut case of cranial-rectal inversion.

I should have posted a bounty for all my rep.

Comment: No problem, it was fun to feel like Miss Marple for a second there. :)

Answer (score 2):

The error suggests the answer:

> 'DataType' does not contain a definition for 'YourExtensionMethodName'

In this case, my guess is that "info" (`ViewObjectDdlCommand.info`) is not a string, but rather DataType.  Try changing it to:

```
OpenCodeWindow(
    string.Format("{0} - {1} - {2}", 
        dsn.Name, 
        objectName, 
        info.ToString().ToTitleCase()),
        schemaItemType,
        objectName);
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. The error message is actually "'string' does not contain a definition for 'ToTitleCase'", and info is most definitely a variable of type string.

Comment: Correction! It was !!NOT!! "most definitely a variable of type string! God, I hate the taste of crow pie! :-S All that typing, and a little inspection would have solved the trick. *sigh*